# Requirements on invoice for expenses to be able to recover the included VAT

Tags: taxes, germany, expenses, vat

A German freelancer needs to buy work equipment (computer, printer, paper, etc.) in Germany, and wants to recover the VAT (*Mehrwertsteuer*/*Umsatzsteuer*) that is included in the price.

Is it sufficient that he gets an invoice on which the included VAT is shown separately? Or are there any other requirements?

For example:

- Must the ‎invoice recipient be the freelancer himself, or could it be a friend? If the recipient is the freelancer, must it show the freelancer’s business address/name, or could it show his private address?
- Must the invoice show the freelancer’s VAT ID (*Umsatzsteuer-Identifikationsnummer*)?

In other words, can the freelancer buy in the same way as if buying privately, or does he have to sign up as business customer in web shops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Freelancer can buy just the same as a private person, and later decide this is a business-expense. Recipient must be the Freelancer himself though, not a friend etc.

The invoice has to fulfill all requirements of a regular invoice under German law, [see here (German)](http://www.hsk-schneider.de/merkblaetter/Merkblatt%20HSK%20-%20Rechnungsanforderungen%20gem.%20Par.%2014%20UStG.pdf)

The usual cash register-printout (Kassenzettel) does not suffice, at least not for anything over 150€.

*One other thing: Some consumer-protection rules like the two weeks return right for goods ordered online do not automatically apply to B-to-B transactions. So be careful when you order something as business!*

Comment: Very small disagreement on the register-printouts or receipts: many of them are designed to satisfy the requirements for small expenses under 150€, for example in bookstores. But always check and if in doubt ask for a "full" invoice.

Comment: @mschuett you are right, and the document I linked also mentions it - edited.